# Creating a pull request to a repository I can push to

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-remote, git-fork

Another git pull request question, but I looked at a lot of them and none answered my question.

I had a branch, say A, of a github repo I am a contributor for and have push rights to, on my machine. I forked and created a pull request for A in the repo and then added and committed more changes to this branch locally.

Now I want to create another pull request for these changes; however, the commits are only saved locally. I want to push to a remote, but

```
git remote -v
```

returns

```
origin   https://github.com/some_user/repo_a (fetch)
origin   https://github.com/some_user/repo_a (push)
upstream https://github.com/some_user/repo_a (fetch)
upstream https://github.com/some_user/repo_a (push)
```

All the links are to the main repo. I looked at my list of repositories and there is no copy of the repo there. So, I cannot change the origin or the upstream to something else.

As I said, I want to push the new changes and create a pull request, but I can't get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I didn't have a remote fork to start with. I went to the REPO and clicked on 'fork this repo' on the top right. This created a copy of the repo on my account, which gave me a link to push to.

After changing the upstream to this link, I could push to this repo, and create a pull request from it.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, you need to define the correct `remote` for your fork and push to it.

1. Visit your fork on www.github.com
2. Grab the remote SSH or HTTPS remote url from your fork:[image]
3. On the command line add the new remote

   `git remote add myfork REMOTE_URL`
4. Confirm that the new remote was added properly by running the command you've mentioned above. You should see the new `myfork` remote listed.

   `git remote -v`
5. Push your commits to this new remote to whatever branch you want:

   `git push myfork [BRANCH_NAME]`

GitHub has a good tutorial on the matter as well: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/#step-3-configure-git-to-sync-your-fork-with-the-original-spoon-knife-repository